# Get all checkboxes within a td

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, prop

I have some check box with a class defined but some of them are children of `td` and some of them are children of `span` and I want to fetch all the checkbox children of `td` by that class. How can I do this?

```
$(".cropFieldChoiceCheckbox").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: is `cropFieldChoiceCheckbox` a class for the checkbox or td?

Comment: "td > input.checkboxclass" should do what your searching for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("td > .cropFieldChoiceCheckbox").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery selectors follow CSS rules, so you can use `td .cropFieldShoiceCheckbox` to select the checkboxes within `td` elements:

```
$("td .cropFieldChoiceCheckbox").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use custom data element for this kind of problems [Form this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-data-html5-custom-data-attributes/)

there something called data in jquery 
[Find Here](https://api.jquery.com/data/)